# ASP.Net Core Blazor: How to load different _Host.cshtml files based on header value

Tags: c#, asp.net, multi-tenant, blazor, blazor-server-side

I would like to load a `_Host.cshtml` file in an ASP.NET Core Blazor project (Server side Blazor) based on a header in the request.

For example:

A client connects to `example.com` and is redirected to a `_Host.cshtml` file specific for tenant A.
Another client connects to `test.com` and is redirected to a `_Host.cshtml` file specific for tenant B.

The `_Host.cshtml` file looks somehow like this:

```
@page

@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>ProjectName</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="images/tenantA/favicons/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="images/tenantA/favicons/favicon-16x16.png">
</head>
<body class="something">
    <app>
        @(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<App>(RenderMode.Server))
    </app>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
    <link href="css/tenantA/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</body>
</html>
```

In the `_Host.cshtml` file, the reference to `tenantA` needs to be set based on the above tenant selection from the tenant URL like described above. Is this possible and if yes how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is one possible solution ,

In _Host.cshtml

You can redirect to any _HostX.cshtml by a dynamic string logic

```
@page "/"
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

@if(Request.Query["test"].FirstOrDefault()=="1")
{
    Html.RenderPartial("_Host2.cshtml",null,ViewData);
    return;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
....
...
..
.
```

This is tested.

You can modify the condition statement to match your case .

Comment: This looks quite promising and simple. I will try this and come back if it doesn't work as expected :)

Comment: This works as expected, thank you :) In my case it was even more easy: I just used `@if (Request.Host.Host == "test.local")    {
        <link href="css/site2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    }
    else
    {
        <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    } `. So basically needed to just switch some css files and svgs and so on :)