# Blazor multiple _Host.cshtml

Tags: blazor

[image]

[image]

I wish to have around two_Host.cshtml. The idea is, i have a login page that have very different required css and js, and a main/dashboard page that has different required css and js as well, I do not want to load all this css and js in the single _Host.cshtml, one for the login page with its staffs and the other for main dashboard area. I already know the concept of multiple layouts but this does not solve the problem. Please help.

Of course i can play with the layout, my challenge is to use _Host.cshtml in Users folder for a select components like UserLoginView.razor and DasboardView.razor to use _Host.cshtml in Pages folder.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverlflow. Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question, and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site.

Comment: @Sukhi, thank you, I have edited the question.

Answer (score 3):

Since the `_Host.cshtml` is a razor page you can write logic in the page to load different CSS files, or you can load different partials or components.

Example

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>My page</title>
    <base href="~/" />
    @if (Request.Path.Value == "/login")
    {
        <link href="css/login.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    }
    else
    {
        <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    }
</head>
```

But if you really need to use multiple _Host files it's possible as stated in [this](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/19744) discussion. This would need for the _Host files to be completely  different applications though.

But you could add something like this:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
    endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
    endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("~/user/{*clientroutes:nonfile}", "/_HostUsers");
});
```

Comment: @ZarkX, thank you for the reply, I have tried you second suggestion but i am getting the error ambiguous Admin/_Host, and  _Host. I even tried to rename the file to something else, still the same error. I have edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: did you change the
`@page "/"`
in the _Host file

Comment: This works for me, but getting issue with the scripts inside the 2nd host.cshtml. Can someone share an exemple of the host file with css & scripts files

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this question and answer :

[ASP.Net Core Blazor: How to load different _Host.cshtml files based on header value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60951806/asp-net-core-blazor-how-to-load-different-host-cshtml-files-based-on-header-va/60952856#60952856)

You can use Html.RenderPartial("_Host2.cshtml",null,ViewData); in _Host.cshtml

Answer (score 1):

in reply to @ZarkX, i completed his code for second suggestion i changed to

```
@page "/user"
```

in _HostUsers.cshtml and changed base tag in head for:

```
<base href="/user">
```

i changed style , js path to

```
<link href="../css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

in _HostUsers.cshtml and work for me.