# Host sub apps in Blazor Server with the sub app fallback pointing to the sub index page

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

So the long story short is, I want sub-domains for a Blazor app. Less significant is that I have a URL rewrite in Azure that will rewrite the URL to the nested app.

What I am trying to achieve is the following.

- When navigating to the `www.sample.com` it hits the main Blazor app in the root
- When navigating to the `admin.sample.com` azure rewrites the address to `www.sample.com/admin`, the users still sees `admin.sample.com` however the app falls back to the sub app index (not the root index)

Note, that the rewrites only purpose in life is to inject `/admin` in to the url, in light of that, it's prudent that the sub apps index works correctly. That's to say, `www.sample.com/admin` should fall back to its nested `www.sample.com/admin/index` otherwise I can't rewrite the following type scenarios  `admin.sample.com/help` -> `www.sample.com/admin/help` etc.

So to reiterate, ignore the rewrite and the subdomains. I need to achieve the following

- `www.sample.com` - loads `www.sample.com/index.razor` with `www.sample.com/_host.cshtml`
- `www.sample.com/admin` - loads `www.sample.com/admin/index.razor`  with `www.sample.com/admin/_host.cshtml`

For reference, here are some pages I have been trying to work through

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio
- [Blazor multiple _Host.cshtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60972771/blazor-multiple-host-cshtml)
- https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/19744

Following the above advice and what I can glean from the documentation, my current structure is as follows

- /

  - _host.cshtml

    - `@page "/"`
    - `<base href="~/" />`
  - Index.razor

    - `@page "/"`
- /Admin

  - _host.cshtml

    - `@page "/Admin"`
    - `<base href="~/Admin/" />`
  - Index.razor

    - `@page "/index"`

**Startup Configure**

```
app.UsePathBase("/Admin"); // <- honestly I have no idea why this is needed
  
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
    endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
    endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("~/Admin/{*path:nonfile}", "/_Host");
});
```

**So here are the problems**

Ignoring the rewrites. The above works for

- `www.sample.com` This uses the root `/_Host` and falls back to the root index as expected
- `www.sample.com/admin/index` This doesn't work, it uses the `/_Host` and displays the `admin/index`
- `www.sample.com/admin` This doesn't work, it uses the `admin/_Host` and loads the root index (not the `admin/index`)

**What I have tried**

- `/Admin/Index.razor` with `@page "/"`. This gives and ambiguous route
- I have tried many permutations of `MapFallbackToPage`, `app.UsePathBase`, `<base>`
- I have also even tried moving the root to its own directory. URL rewrites would support that. However, it causes many of the same issues.

My gut feeling now, it's impossible to get sub apps to work correctly with hosts and fallbacks to the sub index.

Is there another way to solve this problem? or am I writing a completely separate app?

Comment: Quick heads up: the Latin phrase for "and so on" is _et cetera_, commonly abbreviated to "etc." I noticed that you always use "ect.", and wondered if that is accidental, or perhaps it's a stylistic quirk (like the "teh" typo meme).

Comment: @halfer honestly, ect is just a typo, force of habit using the wrong way all my life !

Comment: I've repaired it a few times now - thought I might mention it, in case you're not seeing the edits. I find knowing the full phrase is helpful to remember the abbreviation, and sometimes I find myself saying the long form as I type out the abbreviation `:=)`.

Comment: For the record: I didn't downvote [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67756312), though I don't see how you can even think it didn't deserve the downvote it did get. So your revenge voting was misplaced, as well as uncalled for (as revenge down-voting always is).